# xamarin iOS content files

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

In an Xamarin iOS app I need to deliver a sample text file with the app. When I run the unit test to verify reading I get the error that it can not find the file. I have attempted various places to put the file and have set the action as both Embedded Resource and Content and in all cases I get the not found error.

First where should the files that will be embedded in the App be placed to be included. Second how do you access the file and what path?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go with Embedded Resource, but then you need to access it differently. More info here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/

Basically you need to use reflection to get the `Assembly`, and then call its `GetManifestResourceStream` method with the proper ID.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to place the file in the root of your project, or in any subfolder.  Be sure to mark the file as "Content".  To read it, just use any C# file IO operation, for example:

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("test.txt");

or 

string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("path/test.txt");
```

Paths will be relative to the root of your application bundle, so you do not need to use absolute paths.

One note: be sure that the casing of your paths and file names is correct.  In the simulator it will not matter, since the OS X file system is generally not case sensitive.  However, iOS is case sensitive, so a mistake in casing will cause an exception when running on the device.

Comment: I agree that should work. However when I run the unit test it tells me that the files isn not found in UnitTest/bin/Debug/Samples/sample.txt, I placed the file in the Samples folder. I have linked the samples folder from the library Project to the unit test project.

Comment: I would reiterate the "be sure to mark the file as 'Content'" bit that Jason mentioned. This has burned me in the past.

Comment: Done that. I am doing the unit tests at this point and getting the error when I try to run the test. It looks for UnitTest/bin/Debug/Samples/sample.txt in the unit test folder.

where is the file actually placed during debug compile? I have searched the drive and it does not appear anywhere except where I place the initial file in the source.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure what the behavior should be when you have a Content file in a DLL.  You should probably open a bug with Xamarin - this might be expected behavior, or it might be a bug.